# How to import a .go file in the "include" sense from relative local folder

Tags: go, import, module, package, local

I am trying to include a ".go" file which contains some struct declarations which I will need in different standalone projects

Currently the error is as follows:

```
main.go:8:2: module include@latest found (v0.0.0, replaced by ./include), but does not contain package include/declare
```

Tree structure:

```
/home/dev/go/sample
            include/  
            main.go  
            go.mod

/home/dev/go/sample/include
            declare.go
            go.mod
```

Content of the */home/dev/sample/go.mod*:

```
go 1.14
module include
replace include v0.0.0 => ./include
```

Content of the */home/dev/sample/include/go.mod*:

```
module include
go 1.14
require include v0.0.0
replace include v0.0.0 => include
```

Import from "main.go":

```
package main
import (
      "encoding/json"
      "fmt"
      "io/ioutil"
      "os"
      "include/declare"
)
```

Thank's

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization) out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the assiduous reading proposed by @enzo, my request is now functional

Sample structure:

```
├── go.mod
├── include
│   ├── sourceA.go
│   └── sourceB.go
└── myapp.go
```

The solution is to create a simple correct "*go.mod*" file at the main application level. No need, in my case, to have one in the "include" folder

```
go mod init <name of your app>
```

Contents of the go.mod file:

```
MyApp module
go 1.14
```

Content of *include/sourceA.go* :

```
package include

const ValueA = "a value from sourceA.go"

func FunctionA () {
    println("Hello: sourceA.go")
}
```

Content of *include/sourceB.go* :

```
package include

const ValueB = "a value from sourceB.go"

func FunctionB () {
    println("Hello: sourceB.go")
}
```

Content of *myapp.go* :

```
package main

import "myapp/include"

func main() {
    include.FunctionA()
    include.FunctionB()
    println(include.ValueA)
    println(include.ValueB)
}
```

The import management *(everything is module/packages)* is not necessarily obvious to understand at the start of the apprentices in Go, but once "*understood*", it is since more logical, especially for an "include" approach than have found it in other languages.

Hope this will be useful to others for a better code file organization
*(there are certainly better methods, but this one meets my needs, for the moment)*